# Как сделать пагинацию в рубриках WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть файл который выводит посты относятсящиеся к определённым рубрикам.
Содержимое фала: https://pastebin.com/wL0E1gxC

Пробовал много чего, но кнопки либо не выводились, либо выводились но при нажатии на них перекидывало на site.ru/catalog/test/page/2 и выдавало ошибку 404, ну или же просто при нажатии URL менялся, но отображаемые посты оставались такие же

Comment: Это шаблон типа записи. Тут не может пагинации и к рубрикам (архивным страницам) не имеет никакого отношения. https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: А пагинацию, если её не выводит тема сделай с пом плагина.  Напр https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `paginate_links` примерно так:

```
global $paged;
$paged = max( $paged, 1 );
$per_page = 10;
$total = ceil( $query->found_posts / $paged );
$args = array(
    'total'        => 1,
    'current'      => $paged,
); 

echo paginate_links( $args );
```